# sprintf not work properly in android 5.0

Tags: android, c, android-ndk

sprintf not work properly in android 5.0

```
char buf[128];
sprintf(buf, "%d万", 10);
```

The result in android 5.0 buf is "10",
but in android 4.3 buf is "10万",
sprintf would trim chinese?

Comment: Never use `sprintf`, this is an invitation for buffer overflow! Use `snprintf` instead.

Comment: You could use `wchar` instead of `char` if this type is supported.

Comment: Olaf, snprintf isn't safe too. It does not always terminate the string with zero. ForceBru, unicode isn't supported completely in the android ndk, ...wprintf functions do nothing.

Comment: @Dave: But it does not write beyond the limits. You can terminate the string always yourself or detect that it is not terminated properly. This makes its behaviour predictable.

Comment: @Olaf: yes it doesn't write beyond. But there are implementations like Microsoft's _snprintf wich does not terminates the string with 0 if the buffer isn't big enough, and some programmers doen't know about it

Comment: @Dave: As Microsoft is not standard compliant anyway, they are a very bad reference. The standard is [very clear](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.5p2) about the behaviour.

Comment: How is the Chinese character encoded in your source file? If it uses an encoding that allows '%' as a byte value, you're going to have a bad time. Are you using the same binary for Android 4.3 and 5.0 and seeing different behavior, or rebuilding with the NDK tools for that version? If the latter, are you sure the string is appearing unmodified in the compiler output? How are you examining the output? Is it possible that the output is actually there, but logcat is stripping it?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem on ARM emulator for 5.1.1. This means that `sprintf`()` is probably not responsible, but maybe the font you use hides Chinese characters?

Comment: @fadden:file encode by ut8, the same binary,and the output is actually there, any other phone is ok, but one phone based on android 5.0.1 run wrongly

Comment: @AlexCohn:I did not test in emulator.I print "%d万" with logcat is OK , but after sprintf(buf, "%d万", 10); print buf is "10". Which NDK version your test use?

Comment: @Olaf:the same result with snprintf

Comment: I did not say the error will be gone with `snprintf`. That is likely a Unicode problem. What is your souce character set encoding, what your target encoding?

Comment: Possibly related: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78669

Comment: I use r10e (64-bit) on Mac. I simply displayed the string on the screen (based on HelloJni sample).